# Laravel 5.1 - make migrations not making any tables in the MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I am not seeing any tables apart from Users table created in MySQL DB while using Laravel migrations. I have followed the steps given below

Laravel version : 5.1

1) set timezone to Asia/Kolkata
2) Added following files into Apps/Model

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCardsTable  extends Migration
{

public function up()
{

     Schema::create('cards', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('pin', 10); 
        $table->string('location',256);
        $table->datetime('daterequested');
        $table->datetime('datefulfilled');
        $table->integer('hitcount');
        $table->integer('fulfilledby');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

});



}
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('Cards');

}
}
```

3) Ran the command

```
php artisan make:migration create_cards_table
```

It displayed the message 'Created migration'

4) Ran the command `php artisan migrate`

5) No table is created in MySQL.

FYI, The only db configuration i made is in .env file . I haven't added anything to database.php in config directory (even though i edited username other db related information in the mysql array to match my own credentials)

Please let me know what am i doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create the migration file this way

```
php artisan make:migration create_cards_table
```

it will create a file prepended with date inside database->migrations folder.

Edit that file the way you have done but remember it is not `Cards` but `cards` in the delete `down` function. Also remember in dateTime T is in capital. It is case sensitive. Finally you will have this code

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class CreateCardsTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            //
            Schema::create('cards', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('pin', 10); 
                $table->string('location',256);
                $table->dateTime('daterequested');
                $table->dateTime('datefulfilled');
                $table->integer('hitcount');
                $table->integer('fulfilledby');
                $table->timestamps();
                $table->softDeletes();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            //
            Schema::drop('cards');
        }
    }
```